# Getting keys for specific a value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

The reason why I am asking this question is because I am working with huge datas.

In my algorithm, I basically need something like this:

```
users_per_document = []
documents_per_user = []
```

As you understand it from the names of the dictionaries, I need users that clicked a specific document and documents that are clicked by a specific user.

In that case I have  "*duplicated*" datas, and both of them together overflows the memory and my script gets killed after a while. Because I use very large data sets, I have to make it in a efficient way.

I think that is not possible but I need to ask it, is there a way to get all keys of a specific value from dictionary?

Because if there is a way to do that, I will not need one of the dictionaries anymore.

> For example:
>
> `users_per_document["document1"]` obviously returns the appropriate
>   users,
>    what I need is `users_per_document.getKeys("user1")` because this will basically return the same thing with `documents_per_user["user1"]`

If it is not possible, any suggestion is pleased..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Python 3.x, you can do the following. If 2.x, just use `.iteritems()` instead.

```
user1_values = [key for key,value in users_per_document.items() if value == "user1"]
```

**Note:** This does iterate over the whole dictionary. A dictionary isn't really an ideal data structure to get all keys for a specific value, as it will be `O(n^2)` if you have to perform this operation `n` times.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure about the python, but in general computer science you can solve the problem with the following way;

Basically, you can have three-dimensional array, first index is for users , second index for documents and the third index would be a boolean value.

The boolean value represents if there is relation between the specific user and the specific document.

PS: if you have really sparse matrix, you can make it much more efficient, but it is [another story](https://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwinuemewqTQAhVjJsAKHSCZCisQFggfMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSparse_matrix&usg=AFQjCNF91MbdixWuWFhhOnyJ-uE8l-ItZg&sig2=eh2CqV-PhpMEkw5CWN4X0g&bvm=bv.138493631,d.bGg)